# WPF binding Datasource is updated through reference

Tags: wpf, data-binding

is it possible to set a Datasource through a reference?

```
public partial class GraphView : UserControl
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChartCollection<long>> signals { get; set; }

    public GraphView()
    {
       UCGraph.DataSource = this.signals;
    }
 }
```

and if I set the signals property should it update the Datasource?

```
MyGraphUC.signals = mySignals;
```

It doesn't seem to be working for me. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't directly because the variables `UCDataGraph.DataSource` and `signals` are not connected by any means. They just happen to point to the same instance after you assign them in your constructor (actually they will both point to `null` which is not an instance at all). That being said, you can leverage the setter to do your bidding like so:

```
public partial class GraphView : UserControl
{
    private ObservableCollection<ChartCollection<long>> _signals 
    public ObservableCollection<ChartCollection<long>> signals 
    { 
        get
        {
            return _signals;
        }

        set
        {
            this._signals = value;
            UCGraph.DataSource = this._signals;
        }

    }

    public GraphView()
    {
       UCGraph.DataSource = this.signals;
    }
 }
```

Alternatively you can just `.Clear()` the observable collection and refill it with the elements instead of changeing the collection itself if that is an feasible scenario for you.

Comment: Yep, thats waht I needed! Thanks